# Biblatex Reference list: Emphasizing name with prefix

Tags: biblatex, emphasis

In my reference list (manage with biblatex) I want to emphasize an author.
I did find the `\mkbibnamegiven` and `\mkbibnamefamily` commands.
The problem is my author has a prefix (not a name with space!) and using `\bibnamedelima` do not work.
How can I create the equivalent of `\mkbibnameprefix`?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to tex.SE! Biblatex does know the command `\mkbibnameprefix`. How about `\renewcommand\mkbibnameprefix{\emph}`? You might also use `\mkbibcompletename` if you need to style all 4 standard components of the name (given, family, prefix, suffix) in one go.

Comment: @marquinho That sounds like an answer to me. How about writing it up in the answer section below?

Answer (score 1):

Biblatex does provide the command `\mkbibnameprefix`, just as you suspected. It works analogously to `\mkbibnamefamily` etc. For emphasis, try

```
\renewcommand\mkbibnameprefix{\mkbibemph}
```

If you wish to style the complete name (consisting of the four standard nameparts: given, family, prefix, suffix) uniformly and in one go, you can use `\mkbibcompletename`:

```
\renewcommand\mkbibnameprefix{\mkbibemph}
```

Note that `\bibnamedelima` (and friends) controls the *spacing between* elements of one name part (think *Wolfgang Amadeus* Mozart) and will not help with the emphasis.

Comment: +1 but in a `biblatex` context `\mkbibemph` is usually preferable over `\emph`.

Comment: @moewe: Right! I've amended it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. `\mkbibnameprefix` worked, I only had to change some bibtex entries since prefix is case sensitive ("von" is a prefix but "Von" is not!)

Comment: If an answer helped you, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. (TeX.SX is not a normal, linear forum. It is a Q&A site. This means that there is a strict separation between questions, answers and comments. And that answers should be voted on and accepted. The space here is reserved for self-contained answers to the question only.)